# Minimum dependencies to build android app & generate APK file

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-sdk-2.3

I am basically a .NET Developer but from the last few days, I was working with Ionic. I was able to build and generate APK files from my system where I had installed Android tools from Visual Studio & other dependencies. Below is a list of dependencies that I had installed on my system.

```
- Java (JDK8)
- Gradle
- Android SDK & Emulator
```

By using these dependencies, I was able to build my Ionic App and generate APK files.

My Question is that - Now I am moving my code to a new system. What are the minimum dependencies I need to install so that I can keep the show running as before? I know, below dependencies are required.

```
- Java (JDK8) 
- Gradle
```

Now confusion comes when I think about Android dependencies.

- **Q1.** Installing the Android SDK will be enough for building an app and generating APK files?
- **Q2.** If Android SDK is the only requirement left then from where can I 
    download it for the latest API Level & what is the size of Android SDK? How much space it would take on my hard disc?
- **Q3.** Will I be required to install other dependencies from SDK Manager after installing the SDK to build the app?

  My sole objective is to know the minimum dependencies and their setup to build the Ionic Android App & it's APK generation.

Answer (score 0):

You need Java, Gradle, Android SDK to generate an apk(Android) in Ionic.
So in your case just install the android SDK.
Do not forget to add the path variables for Gradle, Java.

Comment: Is there any zip file that I can download for Android SDK? or I need to download SDK Manager & from there I need to install Android SDK?

Comment: Refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) to download the android SDK. Do not forget to set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable.